# OpenCV detects most rectangular contours only if they are not aligned with the camera

Tags: opencv, contour

Even though I am using OpenCVForUnity, I don't think the problem is about the wrapper, but OpenCV in general.
I basically just use [this](https://pastebin.com/Hp5k7xWH) scipt (which is based on the native c++ [aruco implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/aruco/src/aruco.cpp)) to detect contours by calling the `FindRectangularContours` function. If the markers are aligned with the camera i.e. parallel to the image border, then most of the rectangles are not detected, but when I rotate the camera they are detected.

[image]

The gray scale image is just to show the contours. The found contours are then outlined green.

Comment: can you show the function FindRectangularContours?

Comment: I uploaded the code to pastebin because it would be too much to post here. The link is referenced above at "this" (https://pastebin.com/Hp5k7xWH)